# HTML,CSS,JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как сделать загрузку теста сделанный в блокноте и чтобы принимался и вставал по своим местам?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Пример веб-страницы</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
    <input type = 'file' name = 'test' id = 'file'>
    <button onclick="val()">Загрузка теста</button></br>
</br><div id = 'test'>
        <input type = 'text' name = 'vopros' id = 'vopros' value = 'Вопрос'>
        <label>
        <p name = 'var2'><input type = 'radio' name = 'variant' id = 'var1'></p>
        <p name = 'var2'><input type = 'radio' name = 'variant' id = 'var2'></p>
        <p name = 'var2'><input type = 'radio' name = 'variant' id = 'var3'></p>
        </label> 
    </div>

 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понял

Answer (score 0):

я так понял, в инпут вставляется локальный текстовый файл и нужно его спарсить и данные вставить в DOM посредством Javascript. Если это так, то вам нужно использовать [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader)